# Create .docx file programmatically on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to create .doc or .docx or .rtf file (any Word file) programmatically (using C#) on Windows Phone (Silverlight) 8/8.1? 
I cannot find such information. Thanks.

Comment: you got any solution for this ?

Comment: for WP8 - no, but for Win10 Mobile I didn't check

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible because there are no available APIs to interact with Office Hub. The other answer could not work because a `.docx` file is not a file contaning plain text such as `.txt`. 
For more info about `.doc` files: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doc_%28computing%29#Microsoft_Word_Binary_File_Format

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create it through the Isolated Storage Concept.

```
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
```

Writing Process:-

```
    var appStorage14 = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        string filename14 = "test.docx";
        using (var file = appStorage14.OpenFile(filename14, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
            {
                writer.Write("-- : -- : --");
            }
        }
```

Reading Process:-

```
    using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(store.OpenFile("test.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
            {
                string t;
                t= sr.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(t);


            }
        }
```